# Http request info shows up as blank on server

Tags: javascript

I am using an express router to receive http post request at   `location + "/info"`.
The code for that looks like this

```
let http = new XmlHttpRequest();
http.open("POST",location + "/info"); 
http.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

this is what obj looks like

```
class Obj{
size = "";
length = ""; 
constructor(size, length)
{
this.size = size;
this.length = length;
}
}
let obj = new Obj("test1","test2");
```

The code I am using to set up the router is this

```
router.post("/info", (req,res)=>{
console.log(req.body);
res.send(req.body);
})
```

When I logged the body of the request, it returned a blank array. How do I fix this?

Comment: Your account just posted spam on another question... was it taken over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing results in you not having a header. Without the header, the server won't know how to process the information given in the body.

To create the header, you can use the following code bellow

```
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

This will tell the server to process the information as json, and the console will log the object.